Annotation not processing in Java
I'm making a library/framework that uses annotation processing for configuration. I've registered my annotation processor with @AutoService(Processor.class) and the javax.annotation.processing.Processor shows up in the generated files but for some reason the generated class doesn't show up and when i put a breakpoint in my processor class, it never reaches there
@SupportedAnnotationTypes({"com.example.Config"})
@SupportedSourceVersion(SourceVersion.RELEASE_17)
@AutoService(Processor.class)
public class ConfigProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {
    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations, RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
    // rest of the code here



You need to compile your annotation processor separately, turn it into a jar, then add that to the annotation path. It 'works' if you stick that jar on the classpath but won't from JDK23 onwards. It's very hard to breakpoint them.
